# python 3 installed on ubuntu cannot install python-is-python3

Tags: python3

I'm trying to install python-is-python3 like I've done many times in the past successfully, but I'm getting the following error now:

> pip install python-is-python3

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-is-python3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-is-python3

I have updated and upgraded ubuntu successfully but the error is there.
python3 version is 3.8.10

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a deb package in the Ubuntu repositories.

Use apt instead of pip.

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```